# Unity Google Play Services

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I am trying to get Google play services into the game I have developed. Here is the script I have on my main screen. I get no response out of it at all. I have tried all the different SHA1 codes and I am not sure what is wrong. Any Ideas???

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

public class GPS_Main : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool IsConnectedToGoogleServices;
    public Text SignIn;

    private void Awake()
    {
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        LogIn();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void LogIn()
    {
        Social.localUser.Authenticate(success => { });

    }

    public bool ConnectToGoogleServices()
    {
        if (!IsConnectedToGoogleServices)
        {
            Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
            {
                IsConnectedToGoogleServices = success;
            });

        }
        return IsConnectedToGoogleServices;
        }
    public static void ToAchievementUI()
    {
        if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
        {
            Social.ShowAchievementsUI();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Not authenticated");
        }
    }
}
```

This has really been an annoying event. I have been through many videos and books trying to find the correct fix.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that cause this to happen, the best way to find it is to try connecting your phone and then using `adb logcat` to see what is causing the problem.

Also i have found a little bug in your function `ConnectToGoogleServices` :

```c#
public bool ConnectToGoogleServices()
{
    if (!IsConnectedToGoogleServices)
    {
        Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
        {
            IsConnectedToGoogleServices = success;
        });

    }
    return IsConnectedToGoogleServices;
}
```

This function is always returning `IsConnectedToGoogleServices` initial state.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bit of explanation in this post [Google Play Sign in for Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49826326/3241481)
, however I can't understand from your question what are all options you have tried and where you are stuck in your problem. 6 months old question at the time of me writing this. Hope you've sorted this out already. If so, please post your findings here that may help others.

For anyone landing on this question for an answer, pls refer to my answer on the other post (link above) if that is of any help for your problem and also note down the problem in the code (on the question), I think AminSojoudi tried pointing it out as well. Social.localUser.Authenticate() is taking the argument of a callback function (refer [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SocialPlatforms.ILocalUser.Authenticate.html)). So don't expect it to assign IsConnectedToGoogleServices the result (success or failure) within ConnectToGoogleServices() scope itself. If Authenticate() call runs faster than your code execution, you may get a success, but that won't happen and your function won't return the actual success status of Authenticate() function call anytime. If your rest of the code (leaderboard, achievements) relies on IsConnectedToGoogleServices Boolean flag, then those will not work as well.

```
public bool ConnectToGoogleServices()
{
    if (!IsConnectedToGoogleServices)
    {
        Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
        {
            IsConnectedToGoogleServices = success; // <-- callback result
        });

    }
    return IsConnectedToGoogleServices;  // <-- this won't return the result of a callback result.
}
```